# Can't open text file on scite; Attempting Chapter 4 of "Beginning Ruby"

Tags: ruby, file, text, text-editor, scite

I cant seem to open text files that I created on scite for a ruby based text analyzer I am building as a project from chapter 4 of "Beginning Ruby". When I manually look for the text file that I created in this location C:\Ruby193\bin I see it, but when I go to open it through scite, I cannot find it. Can anyone explain what the problem is to me? Please and Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont use Scite, but if you can open some sort of terminal or file explorer and see the file, then the file is there.  It sounds like when you are in Scite's "Open..." dialog box, not all files are shown because a certain filetype (e.g. *.rb) is auto-selected in the drop-down box for file types.  I would change that to All Files (*.*).   Hope that helps.

Comment: Lol wow. that was such an easy fix. you're a life saver! Thank you!

Comment: No problem, and have fun learning ruby =) .  You can choose this answer if it resolved the question.